# Not waking up from suspend using wireless keyboard and mouse in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, usb, mouse, wakeup

I have a wireless Logitech keyboard and mouse connected to my Dell laptop.  After it suspends, I can't wake it with the mouse or keyboard without opening the laptop lid (I normally work with it closed and use an external monitor).  If I open the lid a crack, mouse movement wakes it.  In the system BIOS I have set the Power Management -> USB Wake Support switch to Enabled.  The suggestions in the responses to question 848698 don't seem to apply because the referenced wakeup file is already set to enabled.  That is on my system:

```
grep . /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/product
```

yields

```
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-11/product:Integrated_Webcam_HD
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-3/product:USB Receiver
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/product:xHCI Host Controller
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/product:xHCI Host Controller
```

and

```
grep . /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup
```

yields

```
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-14/power/wakeup:enabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-3/power/wakeup:enabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb1/power/wakeup:disabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/usb2/power/wakeup:disabled
```

I'm not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve this issue by adding the following line to the root crontab file:

```
sleep 30 && echo XHC > /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

Without the delay, this didn't work because the wakeup settings were modified after the crontab commands were executed.